# Is the word 'space' a countable noun?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

> There's some space in the parking lot
>
> There's a few spaces in the parking lot

Would this make space countable?

Comment: Like a  great many other nouns, "space" can be a count noun as in your second example, and non-count as in your first.

Comment: [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/space) clearly marks senses that are count and senses that are non-count. Even then, there are grey areas (do parallel universes have distinct spaces?)

Comment: There *are* a few spaces in the parking lot.

Comment: The fact that you put an "s" on it and it sounds fine makes the answer "yes."

Comment: There are no grey areas, and it has nothing to with senses. Countability is determined by whether the noun can combine with the cardinal numbers, "one, two, three" etc. That is the only test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Space can be used in both countable and non-countable ways. "There's still some space in the closet," is a non-countable example. You wouldn't put a number on this usage. On the other hand, space in the sense of a parking space is countable: you can go out and count that there are seven empty spaces. So whether space is countable depends on whether it is used to refer to some undetermined area or volume, or whether it is used to refer to a a specific designated block of space. We see a similar example of countable and non-countable when speaking of space on a page: There was some empty space at the bottom of the page (non-countable) vs. Type only one space (not two) after each period.